# Are there any potential risks of avoiding type 3 fonts when using matplotlib to draw figures

Tags: matplotlib

Many conferences/journals start asking me to use Type 1 font in the submitted PDF. So when I use matplotlib to generate figures, I have two choices:

- Configure matplotlib to only use tex fonts

```
rcParams['ps.useafm'] = True
rcParams['pdf.use14corefonts'] = True
rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
```

- Use matplotlib default font but generate png to insert

The problem with option 1 is the tex font looks not as good as matplotlib's default font. The problem with option 2 is it generates non-zoomable png files and may become blurring when I resize the figure.

May I know if you have any experience with the potential risks of the two options, and which one will you choose when creating figures for papers?

Comment: Oh, just to make it clear. I have no problem with the main text generated by latex. But matplotlib by default will use some fancy font to generate figures, which will disappear when you force it to use type 1 fonts.

Comment: As I said, by default when you save as pdf, matplotlib uses Type 3 fonts, which get embedded into the target pdf. When I use these pdf figures in my paper, my paper will have type 3 fonts embedded. Many journals ask submissions to not contain type 3 fonts.